# How can I learn to deadlift with proper form at home?

Tags: deadlifts, form

I've recently started lifting at home, I have some weights, a bench press setup, a barbell and two dumbbells.

I would like to include deadlifts in my workout but I feel like I'm not doing it with correct form.

What can I do at home to learn how to deadlift and ensure my form is good and proper and to improve it if it is not?

I realize that a personal trainer would probably be the best bet but I'd like to neither pay nor go out of my way to do it. I'd like to be able to learn to do it myself at home.

Comment: A simple youtube search can give you what you're looking for. I learned how to do certain exercises by looking at videos and practicing. Also if you have a mirror that will be of assistance cause you will be able to see yourself performing the exercise.

Comment: yeh obviously i've looked at tutorials regarding this, but I can't tell if I'm doing it correctly i'm sure there are plenty of subtle things to look out for which i wouldn't know to look out for. Besides even with a mirror it's difficult to watch myself do it.

Comment: Why? you're standing right in front of it. Also, start with low weight so you can focus in proper form rather than strength, once you got proper form down it should be easier to move onto heavier weights

Comment: @xPeke: diagnosing lifting form generally benefits from a side view, which is also generally difficult and unsafe to do by the lifter while in the middle of a lift.

Comment: @Aequitas: I'd simply recommend recording yourself and watching after to see your form. If you can't figure out where you're going wrong, or you want a second opinion, getting feedback online (after uploading the video) is generally a good way to learn at home. Granted the second part is contingent upon you being willing to post a video of yourself online.

Comment: @AlexL Those are both good ideas, the video will be useful, any idea where I could go to get feedback from the video for the latter point? Would this site be appropriate?

Comment: @Aequitas: yeah, the help section mentions that form checks are a valid topic of question to bring up here.

Comment: @AlexL Thanks, I'll try and make a video sometime. Perhaps you could post what you've said as an answer

Comment: @AlexL It worked for me, but I know it won't necessarily work for everyone. That's why I also suggested low-weight while doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning proper form in any exercise, is something that's hard to judge on your own. But that's not to say that you *have to* have a personal trainer with you.

A lot of people these days post **form check** videos, where they film themselves from different angles doing an exercise, and post it online for response from a fitness community.

I haven't seen any of these posts here that I can remember, but the [Form Check Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/formcheck), and even the [Fitness Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/fitness) are good places to start. The former is a lesser known forum, but more relevant. The latter is for fitness in general, and is a highly populated subreddit.

Comment: even some youtubers in the fitness community offer form checks, like Jonnie Candito